# ES6 find() in array with dynamic id

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hi guys I building a filter, i take the value from the name of an input, so I use:

```
    var el = document.getElementById('editInput');
    var elVal = el.getAttribute("name");
```

so i have the value of the name, now I want to filter in array this value:

```
  var id = elVal;    
  var obj = response.find(function (obj) { return obj.idName === id; });
```

if I use the dynamic variable Id, the filter doesn't work, but if I set a static value, for example:

```
var id = 10;    
var obj = response.find(function (obj) { return obj.idName === id; });
```

It's work without problem, it is not possible to use the filter with a dynamic variable?

the var elVal is not undefined, I dont know how to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe evVal is string. Try double equal:

```
 var obj = response.find(function (obj) { return obj.idName == id; });
```

Comment: Lol the console.log distracted me! in console the id was a number not a string! Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

You can put `id=xxx` into your find function

```
var obj = response.find(function (obj) {
    var el = document.getElementById('editInput');
    var elVal = el.getAttribute("name");
    return obj.idName === elVal;
});
```